# Jquery ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some sorting and editing tools that look like these added in code below:

But if I click Enable sorting first and after enable editing, editing won't work.

UPDATE: For those who need it `$('.content').enableSelection();` is added and it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','ul>li',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id=="enables"){
      $('.part>span').attr('contenteditable','false');
      $('.content').sortable({
        containment: "parent"
      });
      $('.content').disableSelection();
    }else if(id=="enablee"){
      $('.content').sortable("destroy");
      $('.part>span').attr('contenteditable','true');
      $('.content').enableSelection();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content{
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.part{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="part" style="background:red"><span>ssssssssss</span></div>
  <div class="part" style="background:blue"><span>sssssss</span></div>
  <div class="part" style="background:green"><span>ssssss</span></div>
  <div class="part" style="background:yellow"><span>ssssss</span></div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li id="enables">Enable sorting</li>
  <li id="enablee">Enable editing</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put $('.content').enableSelection(); inside the "else if" brackets?

Comment: Now I did and it works. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

remove $('.content').disableSelection(); function from your if condition it should work fine, don't use this function as suggested in documentation

follow below URL for more details.
http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/